# URL rewrite for admin exclude directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL rewrite setup to create nice URLs

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/*(index\.php|blog|admin\/assets|site\/assets|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|products.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I access the admin area with `/admin` the URL is rewritten as `/admin/?rq=admin` because I have a root level directory named "admin". It's probably pretty simple, but how can I edit (or add to) my .htaccess rules so that the url is written cleanly as `/admin/`

UPDATE: 
To clarify, I want to access /admin using `/index.php?rq=admin` and not by calling the /admin/index.php

Here is my apache virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin alex
        ServerName hub
        ServerAlias hub
        DocumentRoot /var/www/hub/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/hub>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that added `DirectorySlash Off` in my .htaccess did the trick. Not sure if this is the correct workaround but it solved my particular problem. I had to make sure to clear my cache fully to prevent cached redirects (thanks Kamil)

In Chrome: `Chrome-> Tools -> Clear Browsing Data -> Empty the Cache`

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `admin` folder to the list of exceptions in your `RewriteCond`. Now, you have exception for `admin/assets` so you can delete the `assets` part and leave the exception for the whole `admin` folder like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/*(index\.php|blog|admin|site\/assets|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|products.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just added some more info - I want to do the opposite of what you suggest - I want to access the admin using the rewrite rules and not the admin directory. The system currently works - but I just need to get rid of that ?rq=admin part of the URL.

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove I'm confused. You have request to `/admin` - you want to process it by calling `index.php?rq=admin`. But: this actually works with your setup! I don't understand, how do you get the `/admin/?rq=admin`? I don't see the rule creating this URL???

Comment: That's why I posted it here :) When I enter a URL that contains any of the root level directories like /admin or /somedir it will always rewrite /somedir/?rq=somedir. Also, if I put a / at the end of /admin/ or /somedir/ then I don't see the additional ?rq=. Strange!

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove go thru all the `.htaccess` files in all parent directories and also check the `httpd.conf` and `apache.conf` config files (especially `Location` and `Directory` sections)... there has to be some more `mod_rewrite` configuration, most likely `RewriteRule` with `[R]` or `[R=30x]` switch

Comment: I've updated the question with my Apache vhost config. I only have that one .htaccess in the root.

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove you missed main config files, I can tell you for sure: the config you provided didn't do the change of URL from `/admin` to `/admin/?rq=admin`. Just trust me a look for the config which did it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19892/discussion-between-alex-holsgrove-and-kamil-srot)